# Run an SSIS package located on a linked server from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, ssis-2012

I am creating a stored procedure on my *First machine* named **Server1** and

would like to call an SSIS package named **mypackage.dtsx** located on my

*Second machine* named **Server2**

Noting that I already linked my *Second machine* to my *First 
machine* and I am using SQL Server 2012

on both of them. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: EXECUTE AT command should work.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ec527f63-d454-4b8a-81e9-23a2ff54c1ca/execute-at-with-dynamic-linked-server-name?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a SQL Agent job on server 2 then running `sp_start_job` over the linked server to execute it. That stored proc is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx).

If your SSIS package is deployed to SSISDB then you could execute it directly via stored proc if you prefer. See the answer on this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/163069/79569).